# ADO.NET Entity Framework: Converting String to Int in Where/OrderBY

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am writing a LINQ query against the ObjectContext.  What I essentially need to do in LINQ to Entities is this (I know this won't work, but I'm doing it this way to illustrate):

```
from c in context.Table
where key == int.Parse(c.KeyAsString)
order by int.Parse(c.KeyAsString)
select c
```

I wasn't sure if this was possible... anybody know of a way?

Thanks.

Comment: Solution with model defined function: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5754218/270591.

Comment: Possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2410070/146325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it the other way around. I assume "key" is a variable int so cast that to string by using ToString() and use that to compare with KeyAsString and in the order by don't use a cast:

```
var keyString = key.ToString();
var query = from c in context.Table
where keyString == c.KeyAsString
order by c.KeyAsString
select c
```

if you have trouble with the order by use a method like `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to pull the results into memory and there you'll be able to cast to int or use a custom comparer.

Comment: Sorting by string value is not going to give you the same order as sorting by numeric value - "11" will go after "1", but before "2".

Comment: @Morawski - **order by C.KeyAsString.Length, c.KeyAsString**

Comment: @Aducci @Morawski: `KeyAsString` must not have leading zeros though ("2" would be before "01") and no negative numbers ("0" would be before "-1").

Answer (score 1):

This is not the cleanest looking solution, but it will work as long as all your strings are valid integers. This can be used with doubles as well

```
var query = from c in context.Table
            let IntOrder = context.Table.Take(1).Select(x => c.KeyAsString).Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault()
            where IntOrder == key
            orderby IntOrder
            select c;
```

Comment: That helped me! Thanks @Aducci !