# Reorder by original index when using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've look around for a solution this problem and although I've found similar I couldnt find an answer to this specific problem. I've generalised the problem but it goes something as follows:

I have the following int[]

```
[423]
[234]
[5]
[79]
[211]
[1001]
```

I would like to use linq to only select the entries that are less than 200 or greater than 300 and then order by the original array index so that the final array is guranteed to be:

```
[423]
[5]
[79]
[1001]
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/2410070/1080742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to object preserves the order in selection, so a simple where clause would do the job.

[Order Preservation in PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In PLINQ, the goal is to maximize performance while maintaining correctness. A query should run as fast as possible but still produce the correct results. In some cases, correctness requires the order of the source sequence to be preserved; however, ordering can be computationally expensive. Therefore, by default, PLINQ does not preserve the order of the source sequence. In this regard, PLINQ resembles LINQ to SQL, but is **unlike LINQ to Objects, which does preserve ordering**.

But if you want, you can select the `index` with the value and later use `OrderBy` on `index`

```
int[] array = new [] 
{
    423,234,5,79,211,1001
};


 var sortedArray =  array.Select((r, i) => new { value = r, index = i })
                         .Where(t => t.value < 200 || t.value > 300)
                         .OrderBy(o => o.index)
                         .Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you filtering objects with `Enumerable.Where` original order is preserved. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> LINQ to Objects, does preserve ordering

Few more words. You can think of `Where` as simple filtering elements in foreach loop, which returns items one by one, in exact same order they are come into loop. Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T,bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(var item in sequence)
       if (predicate(item))
           yield return item;
}
```

Read more on [Jon blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No need to do any sorting, order will be upheld.

```
var someInts = new int[] { 423, 234, 5, 79, 211, 1001 };
var filteredInts = someInts.Where(i => i < 200 || i > 300);

// filteredInts = [423, 5, 79, 1001]
```

Comment: I seem to have found that when the array is v.large sometimes the order is not preserved. My linq expressions is horribly complex but if I can solve this simple example then it solves my main problem.